# URDF coefficients of friction mu1 and mu2 question

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone explain what these coefficients of friction mean?  From looking at this tutorial it says that `"Here mu1 and mu2 are the friction coefficients of the wheels."`

http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDFGazeboExtension

However, when looking at the PR2 urdf for the wheels these coefficients are fairly large (`100.0`).  That seems extremely high for a coefficient of friction.

The coefficient of rubber on dry concrete is `0.6-0.85` for example.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12178/urdf-coefficients-of-friction-mu1-and-mu2-question/) by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-12-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-06-17**:
It really starts to get annoying with all those deleted Gazebo ROS tutorials with no replacement link...,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My best guess is that the numbers were chosen very high to make sure the wheels could never slip, even though the numbers do not make any sense in the physical world.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1